# Build fail if i choose IOS Deployment Target below 11.0.0

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment

I'm developing Hybrid app using ionic 3 framework and everything is working fine when Deployment target is set to 11.0.0 or above.

But as soon as I set iOS deployment target to 9.3 or 10.0.0 or 10.3.0(Below 11.0.0) am getting build failure with below error message.

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So i have to build my app with Deployment target 11.0.0. but if i do that i cant run app in the devices which has vsersion below 11.0.0.

my Xcode version is `Version 10.1 (10B61)`

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be some packages or methods in the iOS native environment which doesn't work for iOS below then 11.0. You should analyse the  error information to see which method or framework is not supported for iOS below 11.0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your pod files i think.

- Click on pods.
- Select one pod on left side and click on build settings.
- Under development section check the version once for all the pods.